# Unable to Migrate Tables In Laravel using MYSQL8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 (just upgraded) and with that it changed my mysql version from 5.7.30 to 8.0.20. I created some migrations but when I ran them using artisan, they failed. I then tried to do `php artisan migrate:fresh` and it dropped all my tables but the migration did not complete. Does anyone know if Ubuntu upgrading my MySQL version to 8+ is indeed the cause of this issue? Nothing else changed. My DB credentials are golden in my .env etc... In the error itself idk why it is trying to make a table with the name of `migration`.

Error:

php artisan migrate:fresh

```
Dropped all tables successfully.

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null' at line 1 (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8 collate 'utf8_unicode_ci' engine = null)

  at /home/projects/inquiry-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null' at line 1")
      /home/projects/inquiry-app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:63

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null' at line 1")
      /home/projects/inquiry-app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:61

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Migration One:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('views')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('answers')->default(0);
            $table->integer('votes')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('best_answer_id')->nullable();
            //Foreign Key
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
    }
}
```

Out of the box User Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `config/database.php` and change:

```
'engine' => null,
```

to:

```
'engine' => 'InnoDB'
```

Or manually define the engine on every migration:

```
$table->engine('InnoDB');
```

Comment: Yep that was the issue, thank you. I also had to run composer dumpautoload